# Conversion of base64 to image results in a "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INVALID_URL" error when array is used.

Tags: javascript, base64

Basically when I use:

```
imageObj.src = "data:image/webp;base64,data[2]";
```

It will give me an error.

However, when I console.log(data[2]) and then copy and paste whatever data[2] is into the code like this:

```
imageObj.src = "data:image/webp;base64,sampleexampleasfnakdjfbaksjbrwkaerhdhcoaunsf";
```

Everything works out. Please help me understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript does not interpolate variables inside strings like some languages. If data[2] is a string, use string concatenation to add data[2] to the URI:

```
imageObj.src = "data:image/webp;base64,"+data[2];
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: In fact, JavaScript it can interpolate variables in latest ECMAScript version, but of course that isn't the syntax.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález do you mean Template Literals or is there interpolation inside double quoted strings?

Comment: Yes, I mean [template strings](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/05/es6-in-depth-template-strings-2/). I guess it wouldn't be possible to use doubled-quoted strings without breaking backwards-compatibility.